# Vue Project Build Success,But Can't show any result on phone

Tags: vue.js

I imported  #vue project  into Hbuilder 9.1 version to create Apk.it was success , but opening that App on phone just showing a blank white screen.
Please need hepl, Thanks

Comment: What is Hbuilder?

Comment: Are you trying to build native mobile app using Vue.js?

Comment: Posting at community of Hbuilder is a better choice (https://ask.dcloud.net.cn/explore/)

Comment: @YashuMittal Yes .it was trying by phone.